# How to specify database in SQL query with Java

Tags: java, android, mysql

I am trying to upload some data to a MySQL database using Java, as I'm working on an Android app. So far, this code compiles and runs, but is uploading nothing to my database. I assume because I'm not accessing the database "streakly" anywhere, but when I've searched around for a way to solve this I haven't found anything.

**Snippet of code I'm trying to upload**

```
 String addStreakName = chooseName.getText().toString();
 String addCategory = prefs.getString("Category", "");
 String addToday = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(new Date());
 if(prefs.getInt("todayOrChosen", 1) == 1){
         int addStartedZero = 0;
         streakList.add(new Streak(addStreakName, addCategory, addToday, addStartedZero));

 try {
       Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("127.0.0.1", "[myusername]", "[mypassword]");
       Statement st = con.createStatement();
       st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO `users`(userId, addStreakName,addCategory,addToday,addStartedZero) VALUE ('"+addStreakName+"', '"+addCategory+"', '"+addToday+"', '"+addStartedZero+"', '"+userID+"')");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the DB on a separate machine or are you trying to use the SQLite on the android device?

Comment: I'm trying to use the SQLite on the Android device, although I now realize this is way off. So how would I save this data to the SQLite server, and then get it another class? Everything I've tried is throwing errors

Comment: I've never done it myself as my needs were simple enough that I could just use a text file, but check [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm) out. It looks straight forward enough.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to connect to localhost, which in your case is the android device. I am pretty sure there's no MySQL server running on your device, thus the problem you see. You can probably connect to a MySQL server using JDBC driver, but I really wouldn't recommend it. Mobile apps live on users devices, and having direct access to your database server is not such a good idea. If you need a local database, you can use SQLite, Couchbase Lite, Firebase, Realm, etc. If you want to then synchronize with a server, you can either implement an application server and sync via REST for example, or use a solution like Couchbase Lite+Sync Gateway or Google's Firebase

Regards,
Vladimir

Comment: Your answer is correct, but I would like to point out that android does have a small SQLite database on the mobile device itself.

Comment: yup, I also mentioned several other persistent storage solutions, that can be used natively on Android. Carter Klein might be following a java tutorial about connecting to MySQL and actually confuse MySQL with SQLite